# print quality for HP mfp 1005 printer

Tags: printing

I have installed HP mfp 1005 in my Ubuntu 13.04. But there are no options like 1200 dpi or 600 dpi. Here are only normal and draft options. But in the normal option still print is not good as 600 dpi in windows. Help me.

Comment: Did you use HPLIP to install the printer? Or just plugged it in?